# design question: best way to aggregate data from several microservices and show in UI

Tags: rest, design-patterns, microservices

we have a scenario where we need to aggregate data from several services and show in UI. The current scenario is when an agent logins in, we need to show cases assigned to that agent. Case information needs to be aggregated from several microservices. There would be around 1K cases assigned to agent at a time and all of the needs to be shown to agent so that he can perform sorting based on certain case data.

What be best approach to show data in this scenario? should we do API calls to several services for each case and aggregate and show ? Or there are better approaches to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You'll certainly not call multiple APIs to aggregate data on runtime. Even if you call the apis parallely, it will be a huge latency.

You need to pre-aggregate the case details and cache them in a distributed caching system (e.g. Redis or memcached) using a streaming platform (e.g. Kafka). Also, store the pre-aggregated case details in a persistent database. Basically, it's a kind of materialized views.

Caching will enable you to serve the case details fast to the user without any noticeable latency. And streaming will help you to keep the cache and DB aggregations updated in a near-real time. Storing the materialized view in database will save you from storing everything in memory. You can use an LRU cache. Only the recently used data will be in cache. If you need to show any case data that is not in cache, you'd read it from database and store it in cache for future requests.

I recommend you read these two Martin Kleppmann articles [here](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/03/04/turning-the-database-inside-out.html) and [here](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2018/10/17/kafka-summit.html)